# Importing data from excel sheet on webpage rather than from within phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Has anyone ever been able to upload an excel sheet to phpmyadmin without doing it manually? On a webpage, I have a upload file with a submit button. Is it possible for the submit button to upload all the data inside of the excel sheet to the tables, without any work from within phpMyAdmin? As a developer, I can do manually upload all the excel sheet information inside of phpMyAdmin, but having a regular staff member use phpMyAdmin may be a bit risky.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything (specifically) to do with WordPress development. If it does, please [edit it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/416127/edit) to explain the problem and how it relates to WP development.

Comment: @PatJ, how can one use phpspreadsheets inside of $wpdb? From what I understand, it can only be used when downloaded with composer